# Error while compiling when using list in C++

Tags: c++, list

I get this strange error when I used the explicit declaration `{ "C++", "C", "PHP" }` of the list :

```
[main.cpp 2021-03-20 22:02:08.850]
,,main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:22: error: syntax error before `{' token
```

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using std::list;
using std::string;

class Person {
    public:
        string name;
        list <string> languages;
};

int main() {

    Person p1;
    p1.name = "Joe";
    p1.languages = { "C++", "C", "PHP" };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What options are you using for your compiler? The default may still be a rather old version of the C++ standard?

Comment: That isn't quite an answer to the question I have asked and is also incomplete (it doesn't mention which version of the compiler is being used). You may want to try using `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` if that doesn't work).

Comment: I don't know much about mingw. All I know is that it use [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as its compiler. I believe it is packaged with some form of IDE but I don't know anything about that. You'd need to see if you can enable using C++11 (or later) somewhere (which is what the `-std=c++11` does; your code uses a C++ features, `std::initializer_list`, which wasn't available in prior versions).

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're trying to compile?  There aren't 22 lines in it...

Comment: Then edit your question with the error you get when you compile exactly the code shown. Nobody wants to spend time on a question that turns out to have a spelling mistake or something that wasn't shown.

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Do you know how to add options, like the `-std=c++11` option mentioned by @DietmarKühl?

Comment: Possibly the OP is using `std=c++11` to compile his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's compiling fine. Check the name of the file and the folder, cause the code doesn't have 22 lines.

> ```
> $ g++ -g -o name name.cpp 
> $ g++ --version
> g++ (GCC) 10.2.0
> Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> ```